# emotion css feature is not rendering the styles (React)

Tags: reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I'm using Webpack 4, Babel 7 and Emotion 10.

I installed `@emotion/core`, `@emotion/styled`, and the recommended plugin `babel-plugin-emotion`.

`styled` is working properly. I can create a styled component and use it. However, if I try to use the native ``` css`` ``` feature it renders the object but not the styles.

```
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core';

const bold = css`
  font-weight: 'bold';
`;

render(
...
<div css={bold}>Something!</div>
...
)
```

If I inspect the markup, I see:

```
<div css="[object Object]">Something!</div>
```

If I use `className` instead of `css`, is the same.
Also if I do it inline or if I use the `css()` feature.

And If I `console.log()` that `Object` the result is:

```
{
  "name": "15b6lyx-bold",
  "styles": "font-weight:'bold';label:bold;",
  "map": "/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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 */"
}
```

Does anybody know what's going wrong?

Answer (score 13):

You might end up with `class="[object Object]"` in div element. If that is all your codes,
you should add JSX pragma `/** @jsx jsx */` thing on top before jsx module

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from '@emotion/core'

...
```

and no single quote at  `'bold'`, it is not valid css writing style

https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop

Comment: Thank you. You should add /** @jsx jsx */

Answer (score 6):

you should add JSX pragma the top of the module like this:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
```

pragma might not work and you should use

```
 /** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
```

instead.

Comment: your worked but I try this doesn't work: "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic",
        "importSource": "@emotion/react"
      }
    ]
  ]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have the [JSX pragma compiler directive specified](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma) at the top of your file:

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic */
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from '@emotion/react'
```

See [this tutorial](https://lawse.medium.com/styling-a-react-typescript-application-with-emotion-98d83807d95c) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

with `create-react-app` using `@emotion/react` 11, React 18, and Typescript 4.4, I was initially just getting `css="[object Object]"` in the DOM. Using the `jsxImportSource` pragma worked for me, but I did not want to add it to every file, so adding this to `tsconfig.json` instead worked for me:

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  ...,
  "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
}
```

Just a few days layer I also ran into this exact same issue using rollup + esbuild (`rollup-plugin-esbuild`), and this solved it for me

```
esbuild({
  ...
  jsx: 'automatic',
  jsxImportSource: '@emotion/react',
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Different front-end tooling provides various ways to transform JSX. Sometimes you need to provide an explicit way for the tool to handle the JSX. My problem was when using Vite. You can add a custom plugin in your plugins section in your `vite.config.ts` handle the `jsxImportSource` problem:

Add this as the first plugin in your plugins array:

```
    {
      name: 'add-emotion-jsx-pragma',
      enforce: 'pre',
      transform(code: string, id: string): TransformResult | null {
        if (/\.[jt]sx?$/.test(id)) {
          return {
            code: `/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */\n${code}`,
            map: null,
          };
        }
        return null;
      },
    },
```

Note, like others mentioned - you still need to add the following to your `tsconfig`

```
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  ...,
  "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the single quote in the bold attribute

```
const bold = css`
  font-weight: bold;
`;
```